# Decompose the identity matrix into several projection matrices. Prove the range of $P_j$ is the subset of the kernel of $P_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, projection, projection-matrices

Decompose a $N \times N$ identity matrix into $N$ projection matrices.

$$
I = \sum_{1 \le i \le N} P_i \\
\forall P_i,\ P_i^2 = P_i
$$

Prove

$$\operatorname{Range}(P_j) \subset \operatorname{Kernel}(P_i)\ \text{when } i \ne j$$

### Researches that I have done

There are some resources showing if the ranges of a set of projection matrices form a basis then the summation of those projection matrices is the identity matrix.

- [Prove that the sum of (symmetric) projection matrices is the identity matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628513/prove-that-the-sum-of-symmetric-projection-matrices-is-the-identity-matrix)
- [Taboga, Marco (2021). "Projection matrix"](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/projection-matrix)

I want to prove the inversed statement.

Comment: Since you may choose $P_1=I$ and all other $P_i$'s $=0,$ the only non-trivial task is the last sentence, i.e. prove that for *every* decomposition as stated, $P_i\circ P_j=0$ when $i\ne j.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be the field of scalars. We must suppose that its characteristic $c$ is $0.$ Assuming
$$
I = \sum_{1 \le i \le N} P_i\quad\text{where}\quad
\forall i\quad P_i^2 = P_i,
$$
let $R_i:=\operatorname{im}(P_i)$ and $d_i:=\dim(R_i).$ Then,
$$\sum R_i=F^N\quad\text{and}\quad\sum d_i=\operatorname{tr}\left(\sum P_i\right)=N$$
hence
$$\bigoplus R_i=F^N.$$
Therefore, for every $x\in R_j,$ since $\sum_{i\ne j}P_i(x)=0,$ all $P_i(x)$'s for $i\ne j$ are $0.$

Note that if $c\ne0,$ the statement is false: a counter-example is $P_1=\dots=P_{c+1}=I,P_{c+2}=\dots=P_N=0.$

Comment: Why $$\sum R_i=F^N$$? Maybe there are a pair of parallel $R_i$ and $R_j$. For the counter-example, it seems that if $P_1 = \cdots = P_{c+1}$, then $\sum P_i = (c+ 1)I \ne I$.

Comment: For *vector* subspaces, "parallel" means equal. And in characteristic $c\ne0$, by definition, $c\cdot1=0.$

Comment: @IvanaGyro: because every $x$ is sum of the $P_i(x) \in R_i$.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the part of characteristics. However for the comment about parallel, meant there may be a pair $i,j$ which has $kernel(P_i) \ne kernel(P_j)$ but $R_i = R_j$, so that $P_i \ne P_j$. If more than one pairs $i,j$ fit this condition, we will not be able to get $P_i(R_j) = 0$ from $\sum_{i \ne j} P_i(R_j) = 0$

Comment: I never claimed $\sum_{i\ne j}P_i(R_j)=0$ but only  $\sum_{i\ne j}P_i(x)=0$ for every $x\in R_i.$ This is easier to prove, and sufficient to get that each vector of this sum is $0,$ since they belong to subspaces which are in direct sum.